# efficient way to process array of objects in java script

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to know the best way to process and prepare relevant data from an array of objects in javascript. I am writing API in where I need to fetch the data and then process and transform data by grouping common keys

Example:- 
I am getting an array of objects in the following way

```
    [
    {
            Name: "test1"
            OS: "Solaris"
            Vendor: "Oracle"
            globalid: "44"
            avgFileSysUtilization: 22.618
            avgcpu: 2.281
            avgmemory: 85.627
            month: "June"
            monthval: "06"
        },
        {
            Name: "test1"
            OS: "Solaris"
            Vendor: "Oracle"
            globalid: "44"
            avgFileSysUtilization: 19.461
            avgcpu: 2.26
            avgmemory: 84.885
            month: "May"
            monthval: "05"
        },
        {
            Name: "test2"
            OS: "Solaris"
            Vendor: "Oracle"
            globalid: "48"
            avgFileSysUtilization: 22.618
            avgcpu: 2.281
            avgmemory: 85.627
            month: "June"
            monthval: "06"
        },
        {
            Name: "test2"
            OS: "Solaris"
            Vendor: "Oracle"
            globalid: "48"
            avgFileSysUtilization: 19.461
            avgcpu: 2.26
            avgmemory: 84.885
            month: "May"
            monthval: "05"
        }
    ]
```

with javascript code, I need to transform this to

```
  [{

        Name: "test1"
        OS: "Solaris"
        Vendor: "Oracle"
        globalid: "44"

        data: [

            {

                avgFileSysUtilization: 22.618
                avgcpu: 2.281
                avgmemory: 85.627
                monthval: "June2019"

            }, {

                avgFileSysUtilization: 19.461
                avgcpu: 2.26
                avgmemory: 84.885
                monthval: "May2019"

            }
        ]
    },
    {

        Name: "test2"
        OS: "Solaris"
        Vendor: "Oracle"
        globalid: "48"

        data: [

            {

                avgFileSysUtilization: 22.618
                avgcpu: 2.281
                avgmemory: 85.627
                monthval: "June2019"

            }, {

                avgFileSysUtilization: 19.461
                avgcpu: 2.26
                avgmemory: 84.885
                monthval: "May2019"

            }
        ]
    }
  ]
```

I have following code snippet to achieve the expected output and I need to know is this correct way or there is a better way to do this task

```
var groups = _.groupBy(result, function(value){
   return value.Name + '#' + value.globalid + '#' + value.Vendor + '#' + alue.OS;
});
      var data = [];
      for (let key in groups) {
        let jsonData = {};
        let commonData = key.split("#");
        jsonData["Name"] = commonData[0];
        jsonData["GlobalId"] = commonData[1];
        jsonData["Vendor"] = commonData[2];
        jsonData["OS"] = commonData[3];
        jsonData["Data"] = [];
        var result = groups[key].map(function(obj) {
          jsonData["Data"].push(_.pick(obj, ['avgFileSysUtilization', 'avgcpu','avgmemory','monthval']));
        });
        data.push(jsonData);
      }
```

Comment: Efficient compared to what? What are you doing right now?

Comment: I am preparing the output array be looping existing data array which has almost 10,000 records and then mapping the common elements. I need to know the better way to do the same task in a more efficient way.

Comment: it would be my code, I will add a generic key to facilitate the work

Comment: Can you control how you get the data? If so, why not get it formatted as you need it? If you can't, I'm not sure if there's a more efficient way to do it than you're already doing it, but you haven't shown us how you're doing it.

Comment: @DanMcGhan I have updated my code snippet in the main post.

Comment: If you are fetching the data via SQL, do as much processing in SQL as possible before fetching the data.  SQL is great for things like aggregates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the surface, your solution seems to be fine. It's using a couple of unnecessary lodash calls and map, which have overhead, but that shouldn't matter a lot unless you have a lot of data.

Don't get me wrong, lodash is great especially for really complex tasks. But this isn't so complex. Here's a solution that uses a single loop to reformat the data:

```
const sourceData = [
  {
    Name: "test1",
    OS: "Solaris",
    Vendor: "Oracle",
    globalid: "44",
    avgFileSysUtilization: 22.618,
    avgcpu: 2.281,
    avgmemory: 85.627,
    month: "June",
    monthval: "06"
  },
  {
    Name: "test1",
    OS: "Solaris",
    Vendor: "Oracle",
    globalid: "44",
    avgFileSysUtilization: 19.461,
    avgcpu: 2.26,
    avgmemory: 84.885,
    month: "May",
    monthval: "05"
  },
  {
    Name: "test2",
    OS: "Solaris",
    Vendor: "Oracle",
    globalid: "48",
    avgFileSysUtilization: 22.618,
    avgcpu: 2.281,
    avgmemory: 85.627,
    month: "June",
    monthval: "06"
  },
  {
    Name: "test2",
    OS: "Solaris",
    Vendor: "Oracle",
    globalid: "48",
    avgFileSysUtilization: 19.461,
    avgcpu: 2.26,
    avgmemory: 84.885,
    month: "May",
    monthval: "05"
  }
];

const formattedData = [];
const groupMap = {};

for (let idx = 0; idx < sourceData.length; idx += 1) {
  const key = sourceData[idx].Name + '#' + sourceData[idx].globalid + '#' + sourceData[idx].Vendor + '#' + sourceData[idx].OS;
  let group = groupMap[key];

  if (group === undefined) {
    group = {};
    group.Name = sourceData[idx].Name;
    group.globalid = sourceData[idx].globalid;
    group.Vendor = sourceData[idx].Vendor;
    group.OS = sourceData[idx].OS;
    group.data = [];

    groupMap[key] = group;
    formattedData.push(group);
  }

  group.data.push({
    avgFileSysUtilization: sourceData[idx].avgFileSysUtilization,
    avgcpu: sourceData[idx].avgcpu,
    avgmemory: sourceData[idx].avgmemory,
    month: sourceData[idx].month,
    monthval: sourceData[idx].monthval
  });
}

console.log(formattedData);
```